# Unity: Remove Prefab variant connection

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my project I have created many variants of a prefab. But I would like to remove the connection to the actual prefab. How can I break the connection?

I am using Unity 2018.3.4f1 Personal.

**Picture of my Prefab Variant:**

[image: Picture]

**Picture of a normal Prefab (what I want):**

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Inside praefab variant you need to break the connection with the original prefab by context menu "UnpackPrefab"

Comment: Which context menu

Comment: Context menus are the ones which appear when you right-click on an item, in this case you have to right-click on top of the gameObject item in the hierarchy panel. There you'll see prefab > unpack, and also the "unpack all" option which I've found more reliant in the past.

Answer (score 0):

@Algok's answer is correct. Not sure why it's been downvoted. A prefab variant is exactly like a prefab containing another prefab, except that it's that root object. That's a little confusing, so I'll give a quick object hierarchy as an example.

We have prefab **A**, a red ball.

**A** (Root object)

- Ball object

Then we have prefab **B**, spikes that can be added to that ball.

In the first case, we add **A** to **B** giving us

**B** (Root object)

- **A**

  - Ball
- Spikes

In the second case, **B** *is* **A**, it's just been renamed:

- <strike>**A**</strike> **B** (Root object)

  - Ball
  - Spikes

In the first example, you'd right-click **A** and click Prefab => Unpack to remove its link. In the second, you'd do the same on the root object, **B**